# Angular How to bind service instance and keep it in different classes

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, multiple-inheritance, angular-components

How can i pass a service method in a super class from a sub class?
I have next service

```
import { Injectable, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'; 

@Injectable
export class MyService {
    constructor(private http: Httpclient) {}

   getData(param1: string, param2: string): Observable<Model>{
   let params = new HttpParams();
   {...}
   return this.http.get<Model>(this.baseUrl, { params })
      .map((data) => new Model());
   }
}
```

Class A as super class

```
export ClassA implements OnChanges {
    constructor(private _serviceMethod: (param1: string, param2: string) => Observable<Model>){}

    ngOnChanges() {
        this.getData(somedata, somedata);
    }

    getData(param1?: string, param2?: string) {
        this._serviceMethod(param1, param2)
           .subscribe((response: Model) => {
           this.data = response;
        }, (error) => {
            {...}
        });
     }
}
```

and ClassBComponent as sub class

```
@Component({
selector: 'class-b',
templateUrl: 'class-b.component.html',
styleUrls: ['class-b.component.css'],
 })

export ClassBComponent extends ClassA {
      constructor(private myService: MyService){
          super(myService.getData);
     }
}
```

`ClassBComponent` is one of many components that extends `ClassA` and share some logic in `getData(somedata, somedata)` method of `ClassA`. Now, if i do that

`this.http.get` in `MyService` throw "TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined". My `http` of type `HttClient` is undefined even if is injected in `MyService` constructor because `'this'` in MyService does not get reference of service anymore and points at ClassBComponent. How can i bind the instance of MyService and used it when i pass the methods in `super()` of sub classes? Do you have any idea how can i do that? Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

If a function is supposed to be used as a callback (event listener, etc.), it preferably should be bound on class construction, e.g. with `bind` or arrow function.

Since `getData` isn't supposed to be a callback but is used like one, it should be bound in-place:

```
export ClassBComponent extends ClassA {
      constructor(private myService: MyService){
          super(myService.getData.bind(myService));
     }
}
```

Comment: @Ramon - Feel free to mark the answer as accepted (with the green check mark) if it solves your problem.

Comment: Thank you for this asnwer, I was doing .bind(this) but it had to be like this answer above where you bind the service that you are calling a function from. Thanks for the eye-opening @EstusFlask